# Nesting GOOGLEFINANCE into a QUERY to filter results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a googlesheet that I use to set up template import files to Amazon. All of my data is stored on a a single tab that I use to drive various QUERY functions on other tabs to filter that data down.

All of my pricing on the central tab is stored in GBP (£) and I need to add an extra condition to the QUERY that filters out everything in column AW below 120 EUROS. To do this I'm trying to wrap the calculation of column AW*GOOGLEFINANCE into the QUERY but I'm struggling

My current formula which isn't taking currency into account but is operational looks like the following - Note: AW < 120 is using the data in GBP

```
={"sku";QUERY('Import Template'!A2:CZ,"select C where CU='Y' and AW<120 
and M is not null and not BC contains 'Large Parcel' and not X contains 
'yes' and AI is null and not C contains 'ASSORTED'")}
```

My attempt at wrapping the GOOGLEFINANCE calculation in is as follows

```
={"sku";QUERY('Import Template'!A2:CZ,"select C where CU='Y' and AW 
'"&'Import Template'!AW2:AW*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR")&"' < 120 
and M is not null and not BC contains 'Large Parcel' and not X contains 
'yes' and AI is null and not C contains 'ASSORTED'")}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about resolving this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"sku";QUERY({'Import Template'!A2:CZ,ARRAYFORMULA('Import Template'!AW2:AW*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR"))},"select Col3 where Col99='Y' and Col105 < 120 
and Col13 is not null and not Col55 contains 'Large Parcel' and not Col24 contains 
'yes' and Col35 is null and not Col3 contains 'ASSORTED'")}
```

Alternative:

```
={"sku";QUERY(FILTER('Import Template'!A2:CZ,'Import Template'!AW2:AW*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR")<120),"select Col3 where Col99='Y' and Col13 is not null and not Col55 contains 'Large Parcel' and not Col24 contains 
'yes' and Col35 is null and not Col3 contains 'ASSORTED'")}
```